# How to install Android jdk, sdk 4.0 in eclipse for Mac OS X?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, java

I am new to Android development. I have both Windows 7 and Mac OS X. I have downloaded and installed Eclipse Indigo Version 1.4.2. I have tried to install Eclipse Helio 3.6, but I can't download it. In `developer.android.com` I found the steps to install Android requirements. I have the following questions:

1. Where to download Eclipse Helios V3.6 for Mac OS X and Windows 7?
2. How to install JDK in eclipse for Mac and Windows 7? I am on this page but don't know how to download JDK in mac? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-downloads-1637591.html
3. How to install the Android requirements in Eclipse and develop a simple program?

Comment: @khantvyas When editing, please try to [improve as much of the post as you can](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74430/why-are-trivial-edits-discouraged). Just removing "Warm Regards", while leaving in "Thanks", strange list formatting, etc. doesn't really help. Remember that until you reach 2,000 rep, at least 3 other users have to review every edit you make. Make it worth it. Finally, editing very old posts like this bumps them to the front page for no good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow instructions here. There are separate packages available for mac os also.

[Installation guide](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html)

Comment: Thank you Raghu. While downloading JDK i face some confusions. There is lot files is there i don't what is required for android development. I will mention the url for JDK downloading page you can see that http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6-downloads-1637591.html. Can you please tell me what i need to download and install? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are downloading jdk for mac then please use this link http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1550

Answer (score -3):

The answers to your questions are on so many pages on thinternet.  Do you know how to use Google?  Type 
www.Google.Com into your web browser and literally type your question in the box and hit search.  The procedure for setting up the Android sdk with eclipse will be everywhere.